# Images show up in Dev build but dont show up after publishing the project asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, image

I am getting binary bytes from database and converting them into to png images and saving them in the /Images folder of the project and displaying them through  tags. the files are created and used in the Developer environment but as soon as I publish it only the files are created in the images folder but it is not being read or being displayed in the IMG tag.

```
public string Image_Binary(string pic_id)
    {
        var imagepath=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"];
        string picstring;
        string pid = pic_id;
        string path = imagepath+ pid + ".Png";
        if (pid != null && pid != "")
        {
             if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
                {
                    picstring = imagepath + pid + ".Png";
                }

             else
             {

                 DataSet picds = DB.fetchdata("select PictureBinary FROM Picture where Id=" + pic_id);
                 byte[] picbin = (byte[])picds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
                 ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
                 System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)ic.ConvertFrom(picbin);
                 img.Save(Server.MapPath(imagepath + pid + ".Png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                 picstring = imagepath + pid + ".Png";




            }
        }
        else
        {
            //picstring = null;
            picstring = "#";
        }
        return picstring;
    }
```

Web.config entry

```
  <appSettings>
  <add key="ImagePath" value="~/ProductImages/"
 </appSettings>
```

Comment: right click your page, click inspect element and look at the file path, you should also 404 errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your images are not stored in the default Images folder then after publishing the new folder will not be included. its not the code fault. as much as i can see the code is correct. check your image path if the folder is created after build.

Comment: solved it a long time ago. but you were right about the problem.